# nested select SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables: Customer, Reservation and Payment

```
Customer
---------------
CustomerID
FirstName

Reservation
---------------
ReservationID
CustomerID (FK_Reservation_Customer)

Payment
---------------
PaymentID
ReservationID (FK_Payment_Reservation)
```

Now I want select table Customer with Reservation to Payment.

Comment: You'll get a lot better feedback if you elaborate more, use correct - or at least understandable - grammar, and maybe provide an example of what you've already tried.

Comment: I agree. Not piling on, but what is it you are trying to do? All you say is that you want to select tables. What is NOT working?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to `JOIN` the tables:

```
select *
from customer c
inner join reservation r
    on c.customerid = r.customerid
left join payment p
    on r.reservationid = p.reservationid
```

If you need help learning JOIN syntax, then there is a great [Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) that will help.